# После вызова Native функции из DLL библиотеки перестает работать ImageIO.read()

Tags: изображения, native, java, dll

Есть код:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/image.png"));
```

Который создает изображения типа `BufferedImage`. Все чудесно работало, но в какой-то момент перестало!

Я это заметил слишком поздно и уже не помню что именно я делал в коде, но после мучительного дебага была выявлена закономерность: после вызова Native функции из библиотеки на *C++* `ImageIO.read` возвращает всегда `NULL`.

А возвращает `NULL` потому что функция `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` возвращает пустой итератор. Тоесть другими словами нет подходящего ридера для чтения изображения. Почему ридеры пропадают - ума не приложу. Никаких ошибок или ворнингов в коде нет.

Кто может помочь?

Comment: А не возможен вариант, что эта ваша native ф-я полностьб блокирует файл? И что за ф-я кстати?

Comment: такое бывает, если изображение corrupted, т.е. с битой структурой.
ImageIO на самом деле не сильно хороший для работы с изображение, однако альтернатив я не встречал.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, после вызова `Native` функции из библиотеки происходит изменение системного реестра или переменных среды, что приводит к некорректному функционированию `ImageIO`. Рекомендую проверить, есть ли какие-то конфликты в системе после вызова `Native` функции, и, если есть, попробовать решить их. Также можно попробовать перезапустить приложение после вызова `Native` функции, чтобы проверить, восстанавливается ли работоспособность `ImageIO` после этого.